# Spring mvc: eclipse link: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'VARBINARY' from a data value of type 'DATE'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, eclipselink, derby

I'm trying to store, amongst other things, launches in a Derby DB.
A launch has a date and whenever I try to insert a launch in the database I get this error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
        Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'VARBINARY' from a data value of type 'DATE'.
        Error Code: 20000
        Call: INSERT INTO LAUNCH (ID, CUSTOMER, DATE, DETAILS, LANDINGATTEMPT, LINKTOMISSIONPATCH, NAME, ORBIT, PAYLOADNAMES, PAYLOADTYPES, TIME, LAUNCHPAD_ID, ROCKET_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [13 parameters bound]
        Query: InsertObjectQuery(domain.Launch@4027c222)
```

Although I specified that it is a date

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date;
```

I get the launches from a rest api and this is how I store them, but I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem because I also get the error when I try to manually insert a launch.

```
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            for (Launch launch : launchRestApi.getAllLaunches()) {
                entityManager.persist(launch);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
```

When I use a Derby server on my machine, it does work and I get no errors. When I connect to the remote database with IntelliJ it also says that the column DATE is stored as a `DATE(10)`, so I really have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: LocalDate !=Date and might be being treated as a serializable mapping- the column definition only affects the database column creation and isn't interpreted or used by the JPA provider.  See http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/new_java_8_date_and  You might also try the latest EclipseLink version to see if it added support for LocalDate yet.

Comment: thank you! it works with the converter